# Recycler view arrange items in a grid that scrolls horizontally

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have set of icons that I need to display in a `RecyclerView` arranged in a grid, and make that grid scroll horizontally. Normally I would use `GridLayoutManager` for something like this, but my requirements are preventing me from doing this. Namely, not only that the items have to be arranged in a grid, but they also need to be added to the grid row by row and not column by column (this is how `GridLayoutManager` does it). So for example, if the grid is is 3x3 and I have 4 items, they shouldn't take positions 1, 4, 7 and 2. But positions 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Any alternatives to the `RecyclerView` that would let me make this work are welcome too.

Comment: Horizontal scrolling plus laying items out in rows doesn't really make sense. How long will the recycler view be if you have 10,000 items? How does it know when to "wrap" to the next line?

Comment: I won't have more than 100 items. But that doesn't matter, you are right. What I'm looking for does sound like a Frankenstein solution. It's better if I figure out the size of the grid and then sort the items myself in such a way so that they get drawn by the RecyclerView it appears as if they've been drawn row by row.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using `HorizontalScrollView` for each of your rows. I am giving you a sample implementation.

You need to have the layout of the item to be in each row first. Let us have a layout like the following.

Let us have a layout like this. Let us name it `item_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some title" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now let us have a `View` class for this layout to be loaded dynamically.

```
public class CustomItemView extends LinearLayout {
    private Context context;
    private TextView mTextView;

    public CustomItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView(context);
    }

    public CustomItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context);
    }

    public CustomItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView(context);
    }

    private void initView(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        View v = inflate(context, R.layout.item_layout, null);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);

        addView(v);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTextView.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Now let us have a class to populate the views inside `HorizontalScrollView`.

```
public class MyHorizontalScrollView {
    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    Context context;

    public MyHorizontalScrollView(final Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        initScrollView();
    }

    private void initScrollView() {
        horizontalScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(context);
        HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams params = new HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        horizontalScrollView.setLayoutParams(params);
        horizontalScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);

        horizontalScrollView.addView(linearLayout);
    }

    public LinearLayout addHorizontalScrollView(LinearLayout linearLayout) {
        linearLayout.addView(horizontalScrollView);
        return linearLayout;
    }

    public CustomItemView addNewEntryView(final String newTitle) {
        CustomItemView customItemView = new CustomItemView(context);
        customItemView.setTitle(newTitle);
        linearLayout.addView(customItemView);

        return customItemView;
    }
}
```

Now get a `LinearLayout` as the scroll view holder and add views to the based on the items to be added in each row.

In the activity layout of your `Activity`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

Now just add your `HorizontalRecyclerView` to this `LinearLayout` by looping through your list, thrice at a time.

```
private LinearLayout mScrollViewHolder;
mScrollViewHolder = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.scrollViewHolder);

MyHorizontalScrollView myHorizontalScrollView = new MyHorizontalScrollView(this.getContext());
myHorizontalScrollView.addHorizontalScrollView(mScrollViewHolder);
myHorizontalScrollView.addNewEntryView("Something");
```

Comment: You're on to something. I don't need a HorizontalScrollView, because I know how many items I can fit in a row. I can use any other container to contain one row of items. This way I'll "trick" the user and RecyclerView because only one column will be visible per screen and each row in that column(HorizontalScrollView in your code) will contain multiple icons.

Comment: did you find any solution for it?