# How to implement Horizontal RecyclerView With Header in my Android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I would like to know the best approach to create an interface similar to the one in the image. I am using the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` to populate my list. Should I have a `TextView` for each category an then a `RecyclerView` under that category? I have multiple view types one for the header an one for items but I would have to know when to add a header in between the items. Also note for my purposes a item can fit multiple categories.

Comment: Please look at the answer here. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49562116/3145960

I have described a similar implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [horizontal recycler view with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211617/horizontal-recycler-view-with-horizontal-scroll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [a tutorial](http://khmertechtrain.tk/index.php/2017/10/03/create-a-vertical-scroll-and-horizontal-scroll-app-like-google-play-store/) for implementing such `RecyclerView`. You might also consider looking at the [github repository](https://github.com/Ranjan101/RecyclerView-Google-Play) as well.

The idea is simple and effective which is described in the tutorial. You need a mother `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView`. The parent `RecyclerView` will have child `RecyclerView` holding the items to be shown in each row. Just follow the implementation of the `SnapAdapter` and the `Adapter` class for the mother and child `RecyclerView` respectively.